# Matlab matrix dimensions in this code

Tags: matlab, octave

What are the dimensions of C and nx? Code in Matlab. Loops produce 49 elements for nx but the other line suggests 16? `x` is input image of dimensions `M,N`.

```
function y=sri1(x)

[M,N]=size(x);
%e=zeros(M,N);
for i=1:2
   for j=1:2
      y(i:2:2*M,j:2:2*N)=x;
   end
end

T=5;
ix=[-1 -1 1 1];
iy=[-1 1 -1 1];
mx=[0 0 1 1];
my=[0 1 0 1];
cnt=1;
for i=-2:4
   for j=-2:4
      nx(cnt)=i;ny(cnt)=j;cnt=cnt+1;
  end
end
%nx=[0 1 1 0 -1 -1  0  1 2 2 0 1 -1 -1 2 2];
%ny=[0 0 1 1  0  1 -1 -1 0 1 2 2 -1  2 -1 2];

th=8;
for i=T:M-T
   for j=T:N-T
      for k=1:4
      C(:,k)=diag(x(i+ix(k)+nx,j+iy(k)+ny));
    end
      r=diag(x(i+nx,j+ny));
      s=diag(x(i+mx,j+my));
      if det(C'*C)==0|var(s)<th
         a=ones(4,1)/4;
      else
         a=inv(C'*C)*(C'*r);
         %a=fun(C,r);
      end
      y(2*i,2*j)=sum(a.*s); 
      if y(2*i,2*j)<0|y(2*i,2*j)>255
         a=ones(4,1)/4;y(2*i,2*j)=sum(a.*s);
        end
   end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that the commented out lines are correct? Are you sure you want to use `i=-2` and `j=-2` as starting values of your loops ?

Comment: This is the code that I was given, I have no clue where it comes from unfortunately.

Comment: Then it would be better to write your own code for your task/problem!

Comment: your comment shows you obviously know the final size of the generated arrays. So I'm closing this as unclear as what you are asking.

Comment: It aint python, for loops are using matlab syntax clearly. ;)

Comment: @carandraug If I knew I would not be asking. C is not defined anywhere in the code.

Comment: `C` is defined in the nested `for` loop: `C(:,k)=diag(x(i+ix(k)+nx,j+iy(k)+ny));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the sizes of vectors and matrices, I would recommend that you look up the command [size](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html).

As in, for example:

```
size( C )
size( nx )
```

You could also print the objects themselves, or use the debugging tools in MATLAB, to help figuring out if your program works correctly. Look at the different parts separately too, for example checking how the specified part of *x* looks, and how the diagonal looks, one by one.

In your case, it seems that *nx* correctly has 49 entries. Each loop will run 7 times, with each input -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

*C* seems to end up as 49 by 4. Each time in the inner loop, columns 1 to 4 of the matrix get set as the diagonal of a 49 by 49 part of the *x* matrix. This is of course a 49 elements long vector.